# Why is a class implementing an interface not compatible with the interface type when used in generics?

Tags: delphi, generics

Does anyone know why there's an error on the indicated lines?

Seems like a compiler bug according to the [Type Compatibility](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity) page.
Wildcard is T1, and TStringWildcard2 is T2.

Also according to this

> An expression of type T2 can be assigned to a variable of type T1 if the value of the expression falls in the range of T1 and at least one of the following conditions is satisfied: T1 is the IUnknown or IDispatch interface type and T2 is Variant or OleVariant. (The variant's type code must be varEmpty, varUnknown, or varDispatch if T1 is IUnknown, and varEmpty or varDispatch if T1 is IDispatch.)

If T1 is IUnknown and T2 is OleVariant, an expression of type T2 can be assigned to a variable of type T1 - therefore the second error line should compile as well.

ACollection2 := ACollection1; // theoretically should compile, but doesn't.
Since LWildcard := TStringWildcard2.Create (compiles, since LWildcard is declared as a variable of the Wildcard interface, and TStringWildcard2 implements the Wildcard interface).

```
As such, therefore, ACollection2 (TDictionary<string, Wildcard> ) := ACollection1; (TDictionary<string, TStringWildcard2>) should compile right?

program TestCollections;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections;
type
  Wildcard = interface
  ['{941128E5-D87C-4E3E-98D8-CF45EE6FEC09}']
    procedure Clear;
  end;
  Wildcard<T> = interface(Wildcard)
    function  getMatch: T;
  end;
  TParent = class(TInterfacedObject)
  end;
  TStringWildcard1 = class(TParent, Wildcard<string>)
    function  getMatch: string;
    procedure Clear;
  end;
  TStringWildcard2 = class(TParent, Wildcard, Wildcard<string>)
    function  getMatch: string;
    procedure Clear;
  end;

{ TStringWildcard1 }

procedure TStringWildcard1.Clear;
begin
end;

function TStringWildcard1.getMatch: string;
begin
  Result := 'String match 1';
end;

{ TStringWildcard2 }

procedure TStringWildcard2.Clear;
begin
end;

function TStringWildcard2.getMatch: string;
begin
  Result := 'String match 2';
end;

var
  LWildcard: Wildcard;
  ACollection1: TDictionary<string, TStringWildcard2>;
  ACollection2, ACollection3: TDictionary<string, Wildcard>;
  ACollection4: TDictionary<string, IUnknown>;
begin
  LWildcard := TStringWildCard2.Create; // <-- TStringWildcard2 compatible with Wildcard
// Since TStringWildcard2 is compatible with Wildcard, therefore, 
// ACollection1 should be compatible with ACollection2
  ACollection1 := TDictionary<string, TStringWildcard2>.Create;
  ACollection2 := ACollection1;
  ACollection4 := TDictionary<string, OleVariant>.Create;
end.
```

Comment: You're likely to get a faster response if you reduce the example to something smaller. It doesn't look like all these lines are contributing to the problem that you describe. I bet you could capture the problem in 10 lines or less.

Answer (score 4):

There is no compiler bug here. The compiler is behaving as designed. The assignments fail because the types are indeed not compatible. Delphi generic types are [invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Formal_definition).

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Overloads_and_Type_Compatibility_in_Generics) says:

> Two instantiated generics are considered assignment compatible if the base types are identical (or are aliases to a common type) and the type arguments are identical.

Now, let's look at the first assignment that fails:

```
var
  ACollection1: TDictionary<string, TStringWildcard2>;
  ACollection2: TDictionary<string, Wildcard>;
....
ACollection2 := ACollection1;
```

This fails because the type arguments are not identical.

And for `ACollection4` we have

```
var
  ACollection4: TDictionary<string, IUnknown>;
....
ACollection4 := TDictionary<string, OleVariant>.Create;
```

Again, the type arguments are not identical.

---

There's a very good reason for the language designers choosing to make generic types invariant. Consider the following example.

```
type
  TClass1 = class(TObject)
  end;
  TClass2 = class(TClass1)
  end;

var
  List1: TList<TClass1>;
  List2: TList<TClass2>;
....
List2 := TList<TClass2>.Create;
List1 := List2; // does not compile, but let's imagine that it did
List1.Add(TClass1.Create);
```

Since `List1` and `List2` are the same object, we have now succeeded in putting an object of type `TClass1` into `List2` which breaks the type system.

In fact your attempt to assign

```
ACollection2 := ACollection1;
```

illustrates this very issue. Suppose that assignment was valid and then you added to `ACollection2` something that implemented `Wildcard` but that was not `TStringWildcard2`. Then that same thing would have been added to `ACollection1` and all of a sudden you'd succeeded in adding to `ACollection1` something that was not `TStringWildcard2` and you've broken the type system.

In languages that support generic variance there need to be runtime checks to stop this happening. As it happens, only yesterday our very own Jon Skeet blogged on this very topic: [Array covariance: not just ugly, but slow too](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/06/22/array-covariance-not-just-ugly-but-slow-too.aspx). So, be careful what you wish for!

---

Because of this the Delphi designers elected to make Delphi generic types invariant.

Comment: David, your example is of classes. I hope you noticed that in my example, Wildcard is an interface and that you also noticed I'm trying to call the Wildcard interface methods implemented by TStringWildcard2.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Delphi generics are type invariant. I also outlined the problem in your context. What
do you make of the documentation link that I quoted? You must adjust your mindset and entertain the possibility that
the behaviour is as designed.

Comment: Your mind is set. Your answer is answering a different set of question. All I'm trying to do is call the interface methods implemented by at least 5 different collections, each of which implements the basic interface.

Comment: Your code does not call methods, it attempts to perform assignments. I gave you a link to the documentation that explains the rules for type compatibility of generics. That's the key. *Two instantiated generics are considered assignment
compatible if the base types are identical (or are aliases to a
common type) and the type arguments are identical.* Do you see how that applies here? Do you see that your type arguments are not identical.

Comment: In order to call method, first, I must assign isn't it? If I can't even assign, showing the code to call the method is superfluous!

Comment: Indeed so. The question therefore is all about type compatibility. And hence the answer. I'm curious to understand in what way I'm failing to make myself clear. It's clear to me but I'm obviously not making it clear to you. Do you understand the issues of generic type variance and invariance?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess your explanation was not good enough ;) http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116771

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, it's a reflection you made that is wrong. Using a compatible type as a generic type argument does **not** make the generic type compatible as well. This has to do with [covariance and contravariance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).