# Casting TList<T:class> to TList<W:class>

Tags: delphi, casting, rtti, generic-collections, tlist

I have a list of type `TList<TForm>`. I need to cast it and use it as `TList<TObject>` like this:

```
procedure mainForm.testCast;
var
  listT: TList<TForm>;
  listW: TList<TObject>;
  obj: TObject;
begin
  listT := TList<TForm>.create;
  listT.add(form1);
  listT.add(form2);

  listW := TList<TObject>(listT);  // Casting is OK

  // This works, but is this fine?
  for obj in listW do
    memo1.lines.add(obj.className);

end;
```

The sample works as expected, but is it ok to cast like this between generic lists? Will this cause some data structure corruption etc? 
I use it only for looping (`DoGetEnumerator`) purposes and some string checks i.e. I'll not add/remove items.

The real function is little more complicated. It gets reference to `listT` using RTTI in a `TValue`.
The main goal is not to link `FMX.Forms` in my unit.

**Update:**
[Why are TGeneric<Base> and TGeneric<Descendant> incompatible types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687755/why-are-tgenericbase-and-tgenericdescendant-incompatible-types)

Comment: That will work fine, but it's a bit sketchy. I doubt that you need to use a cast here in any case. You can reach the enumerator through RTTI.

Comment: Since `TForm` is derived from `TObject` and `TList<TSomeThing>` is a generic list of typed pointers, there is nothing wrong with what you are doing. That is, using methods from the base class.

Comment: @LURD I don't think that is right. `TList<TObject>` is not a base class for `TList<TForm>`. You will find that `TList<TForm> is TList<TObject>` evaluates as `False`. The common base is `TList<T>`. Another way to think about it. If it were just using methods from the base class, why would the cast be needed?

Comment: @LURD Sorry, I got the code wrong in that comment. Of course, `is` is no good here because these are both classes. I meant `TList<TForm>.InheritsFrom(TList<TObject>)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, with base class I meant primarily `TForm`vs `TObject`. I would expect that `TList<TForm>` would behave in a similar way as `TList<TObject>`, while this would not be true for any `TList<T>`.

Comment: @LURD The code in the question will work, but it only does so by way of undocumented implementation detail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'm not with you here, "undocumented implementation detail". Why would `TList<T>` handle `T` different if `T` is any object which is a based on `TObject`? Technically i guess it would be possible, but is that not a long shot?

Comment: @LURD If the cast was legal then it could be performed with `as`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code will work, but it somewhat dubious in my view. Simply put the cast is not legal because

```
TList<TForm>.InheritsFrom(TList<TObject>)
```

is false. So a  `TList<TForm>` object is not a `TList<TObject>`. If it were, then the cast would not be needed.

That this is so is because Delphi's generic types are invariant. More details can be found here: 
[Why is a class implementing an interface not compatible with the interface type when used in generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258226/why-is-a-class-implementing-an-interface-not-compatible-with-the-interface-type)

If you have any difficulty understanding why the designers made generic types invariant, consider for a moment the effect of writing `listW.Add(TObject.Create)` in your code. Think what it means to the true underlying object of type `TList<TForm>`.

So the language promises you nothing. You are venturing outside its guarantees. It so happens that the implementation of these two un-related types is compatible enough for your code to work. But that is really just an accident of implementation.

Since you are already using RTTI, then I suggest that you iterate over the list with RTTI. You can call `GetEnumerator` and so on using RTTI. That way you will call the actual methods of the object.

Comment: Thank you @David-Heffernan! My goal is to enumerate Form's children using RTTI. The enumerator returns TEnumerator<TFmxObject> but I do not want to include FMX.Types in my unit. So I wanted to cast the result to something like TEnumerator<TComponent> which rises the question above.

Comment: You need **not** to cast to a concrete type. You need to stick entirely in the world of RTTI. Your code will work, but it relies on implementation detail to do so.

Comment: "You need to stick entirely in the world of RTTI" - good point :)

Comment: by the way my simple (and may be wrong) logic was: if W & T are instances of a class then you can cast them to a common ancestor i.e. TObject given that you are sure they are class instances.

Comment: `W` and `T` have a common ancestor. But that's not what we are dealing with. It's `TList<W>` and `TList<T>` and we are into generic invariance. My answer at the question I linked to, and the links from there, are worth reading. Perhaps I'll be more successful in helping you understand generic variance than I was with the asker at that question!  ;-)